# behavior of the compiler using classes

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, types

```
#include <list>
using std::list;
class foo { ...
class bar : public foo { ...
static void print_all(list<foo*> &L) { ...
list<foo*> LF;
list<bar*> LB;
...
print_all(LF); // works fine
print_all(LB); // static semantic error
```

I think i know why the compiler will not allow the second call. Can anyone give an example of bad things that could happen if the compiler accepts this kind of call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different things going on in the code, with different explanations. The first problem is that different instantiations of a template are unrelated, even if the instantiating types are related. In this particular case `std::list<foo*>` has no relationship with `std::list<bar*>`, even if `foo` is a base of `bar`. This is part of the design of the language and nothing can be done.

The second problem, which is not what the compiler is complaining about is that in general a container of `derived` cannot be used by reference as a container of `base`. That is the issue that @templatetypedef brought up --but again, this is not the issue in the code, it would be in a different example:

```
void f( base** p );
int main() {
   derived *d;
   f( &d );          // error
}
```

In this case, the issue is that, as @templatetypedef points out that using a pointer/container of `derived` in place of a pointer/container to `base` *in a non-const manner* is prone to errors, as you could store non-`derived` types on the pointer/container.

Answer (score 3):

Sure!  What if print_all does this:

```
L.push_back(new Foo);
```

Now your list of Bar pointers has a pointer to a Foo object that is not a Bar.  If you then try to call a method in Bar not present in the Foo class, you'll get some sort of serious runtime problem since the method doesnt exist in the Foo object.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Different template instantiations are unrelated types. Even if the container was `const` (and thus you could not make any change that would violate the constraints) it would not be allowed.

Comment: @DavidRodriguez-dribeas- Definitely.  I think that the OP's question is why that rule exists.

Comment: I am not so sure about it. There are many uses of templates that are not containers. Specializations allow for complete different types, and there is no way to translate the relationship between instantiating types to the instantiated templates. Consider that the relationships might be inheritance or any other one (implicitly constructible from is the first that comes to mind). Also note that there are similar examples in the language (const-correctness) where the specification adds flexibility whenever it is safe, but that is not done in this particular case ...

Comment: ... for example, `char ** p` is implicitly convertible to `char const * const *`, but not to `char const **` (the use case and the potential pitfalls are the same as your container example, but in this case the language allows the *safe* use, while limiting the *unsafe* one)